# jQuery contains ignoring HTML

Tags: jquery, html, codemirror

I have this HTML code:

```
<pre class="">
    <span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">
        <span class="cm-operator">=</span>
        <span class="cm-operator interactive-linter-warning">===</span>
        <span class="cm-operator interactive-linter-warning interactive-linter-error">===</span>
    </span>
</pre>
```

It looks, rendered, like:

```
=======
```

I need a way to select the `<pre/>` element basing the selection on the content of the element, I've tried with `:contains`:

```
$("pre:contains('=======')")
```

But it doesn't work, probably because it considers even the HTML contained inside the `<pre/>` element.

How can I ignore the HTML and consider just the text?

Comment: That is not how it looks rendered.

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: It's on multiple lines, with whitespace: http://jsfiddle.net/VtzB8/

Comment: On CodeMirror it's all in a single line, by the way this doesn't answers the question.

Comment: `$("pre").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().indexOf('=======') != -1 });`

Comment: @f00bar That still won't work because there is never any sequence of those characters in the `.text()`

Comment: @FezVrasta It kind of does. Check my answer and you'll understand why it explains why your approach doesn't work

Comment: @RGraham  it does acualy .. returns the text expected using firebug console `$('<pre class=""><span style="padding-right: 0.1px;">'+'<span class="cm-operator">=</span><span class="cm-operator interactive-linter-warning">===</span><span class="cm-operator interactive-linter-warning interactive-linter-error">===</span></span></pre>').filter(function(){ return $(this).text().indexOf('=======') != -1 }).text()`

Comment: @f00bar That's not a valid representation of the OP's markup as you have no whitespace. Add some line breaks and tab characters into your string and you'll see why it doesn't work.

Comment: @f00bar's code works in CodeMirror.

Comment: yep, this is right, there may have some spaces sometimes, then instead of indexOf, a regular expression may help but this might be costly

Comment: @FezVrasta I'm not arguing that his code doesn't work, it does. It's just not an accurate representation of your problem. If your HTML is all in one line then great - use that. @f00bar indexOf introduces its own problems. What if the spans contain an extra `=`? Yours will also match for any number of `=` greater than or equal to 7. But hey, if it works for the OP that's the main thing

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you explain why you are using spans and css inside pre tag?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give a try to :

```
$("pre").filter(function(){ return $(this).text().indexOf('=======') != -1 });
```

Preventing spaces to get in between equal signs

```
$("pre").filter(function(){
      return $(this).text().replace(/=\s+/g,'=').indexOf('=======') != -1
  }
);
```

Still not lightweight though

Answer (score 1):

I would [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) by text on each `pre` element and trim that extra whitespace:

```
$("pre").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, "") === "=======";
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98D7P/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('pre').each(function(){
   var val = $.trim($(this).text().replace(/\n+\s+/g,''));
   if( val == '======='){
      alert($(this).attr('class'));    
   }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xD3kP/)